# How can I abstract/generalize functions that perform similar, but just slightly different tasks? (mostly different and slightly complex selectors)

Tags: javascript, jquery

An example of one instance of an anonymous function I'm trying to generalize

```
$('.FFEC-Display').each(function(i, el){
    var title = $(el).find('h3').text().replace(blacklistRegexp, '').trim();
    /* you can ignore the code in here
    var tomato = findTomato(title, tomatoes);
    var classes = ["poster-width", "overlay"];
    var templateData = tomato ? prepareData(tomato, classes) : { query: title, classes: namespaceClasses(classes) };
    */
    $(el).find('.movie-link').prepend(Handlebars.templates.ratings(templateData));
});
```

Here's another instance:

```
$('.MovieItemsRotator .item').each(function(i, el){
    var title = $(el).find('.Title').text().replace(blacklistRegexp, '').trim();
    /* you can ignore the code in here
    var tomato = findTomato(title, tomatoes);
    var classes = ["overlay", "overlay-poster"];
    var templateData = tomato ? prepareData(tomato, classes) : { query: title, classes: namespaceClasses(classes) };
    */
    $(el).prepend(Handlebars.templates.ratings(templateData));
});
```

I have three more instances of these (plan on adding more), they're all very similar, but just different enough to give me quite a headache when trying to create a DRY-er function.

Full code on [Git Repo](https://github.com/cheapsteak/Chrome-Movie-Buddy/blob/master/moviebuddy.js)

edit-addition:
One of the main difficulties is the last part, sometimes I want to do `$(el).prepend`, sometimes `$(el).append`, or `$(el).after`, or `$(el).find('something').prepend`, or `$(el).closest('something').prepend/append/after`

Comment: Find the common bits. Identify how they correlate. Factor them out.. one approach is to use closures to create functions that return specialized functions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would n't go completely crazy making it DRY if they are of different sections with different functionality, for the purpose of **maintainability** and **readability** and for any **future enhancements**. But some common functionalities can be separated out.

Example i would always keep `moviedetailsmaininfo`, `BoxOfficeMovie`, `MovieItemsRotator` etc sections separate as i want to have it more readable/maintainable and since they sounds like serving its own set of a functionality (But you would know better), keeping them separate itself would make sense according to me.

Something along these lines?

```
function getTemplateData(title, classes) {
    var tomato = findTomato(title, tomatoes);
    return tomato ? prepareData(tomato, classes) : {
        query: title,
        classes: namespaceClasses(classes)
    };
}

function getTitle(elem) {
    return elem.text().replace(blacklistRegexp, '').trim();
}


$('.FFEC-Display').each(function (i, el) {
    $(el).find('.movie-link').prepend(Handlebars.templates.ratings(getTemplateData(getTitle($(el).find('h3')), ["poster-width", "overlay"])));
});
//http://cineplex.com/Theatres/TheatreDetails/Cineplex-Cinemas-Mississauga-formerly-Coliseum-Mississauga-.aspx

$('.Listing .moviedetailsmaininfo').each(function (i, el) {

    $(el).find('.Poster').after(Handlebars.templates.ratings(getTemplateData(getTitle($(el).find('h3')), ["inline", "poster-width", "text-center", "below-poster"])));
});
//homepage
$('.BoxOfficeMovie').each(function (i, el) {
    $(el).append(Handlebars.templates.ratings(getTemplateData(getTitle($(el).find('a')), ["inline", "float-right"])));
});
//homepage
$('.MovieItemsRotator .item').each(function (i, el) {

    $(el).find('div').first().css('position', 'relative').prepend(Handlebars.templates.ratings(getTemplateData(getTitle($(el).find('.Title')), ["overlay"])));
});
//http://cineplex.com/Movies.aspx
$('.Movies .Movie').each(function (i, el) {
    $(el).find('.MoviePoster').append(Handlebars.templates.ratings(getTemplateData(getTitle($(el).find('h3')), ["inline", "full-center"])));
});
```

Comment: Thanks, This looks so much better. Going too crazy in making it dry was indeed what was giving me a headache. I ended up with function calls that were unintuitive and very ugly `{
                $loopThrough: $('.FFEC-Display'),
                title: $(el).find('h3').text(),
                classes: ["poster-width", "overlay"],
                outputHandler: function (compiled) {
                    $(el).find('.movie-link').prepend(compiled);
                }
            };`

Comment: @CheapSteaks Yes you are right, you don't want to trade some of the factors as i mentioned for just making it completely dry, which may turn out expensive later :) . As it is visible in your sections that some places you append, after, etc... So better keep different functionalities separate.

Answer (score 1):

Something like this may work:

```
function myFunction(selectorA, selectorB, selectorC) {
    $(selectorA).each(function(index, el) {
           var title = $(el).find(selectorB).(blacklistRegexp, '').trim();
           /* ignored code */
           if ( selectorC ) {
               $(el).find(selectorC).prepend(Handlebars.templates.ratings(templateData));
           }
           else {
               $(el).prepend(Handlebars.templates.ratings(templateData));
           }
    });
}

myFunction(".FFEC-Display", "h3", ".movie-link");
myFunction(".MovieItemsRotator .item", ".Title");
```

Answer (score 1):

Okay, this is just a starting point but:

```
$('.FFEC-Display').each(function(i, el){
    var title = magical_title_function(el,'h3');
    /* you can ignore the code in here
    var tomato = findTomato(title, tomatoes);
    var classes = ["poster-width", "overlay"];
    var templateData = tomato ? prepareData(tomato, classes) : { query: title, classes: namespaceClasses(classes) };
    */
    magical_prepend_function(el, templateData, selector,'.movie-link')
});


$('.MovieItemsRotator .item').each(function(i, el){
    var title = magical_title_function(el,'.Title');
    /* you can ignore the code in here
    var tomato = findTomato(title, tomatoes);
    var classes = ["overlay", "overlay-poster"];
    var templateData = tomato ? prepareData(tomato, classes) : { query: title, classes: namespaceClasses(classes) };
    */
    magical_prepend_function(el, templateData)
});

function magical_title_function(el,selector){
    return $(el).find(selector).text().replace(blacklistRegexp, '').trim();
}
function magical_prepend_function(el, templateData, selector){
    if(selector==undefined){
        $(el).prepend(Handlebars.templates.ratings(templateData));
    } else {
        $(el).find(selector).prepend(Handlebars.templates.ratings(templateData));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

so here is a crazy answer that won't be suggested even by myself. just post it for trying to think in another way.

make a json like:

```
json = [
  {target: '.FFEC-Display', title : 'h3', action :"$(el).find('.movie-link').prepend(Handlebars.templates.ratings(templateData));"},
  {target: '.MovieItemsRotator .item', title: '.Title', action: "$(el).prepend(Handlebars.templates.ratings(templateData));"}
  ...
]
```

then iterator it like:

```
$.each(json, function(index, j){
  $(j.target).each(function(i, el){
    var title = $(el).find(j.title).text().replace(blacklistRegexp, '').trim();
    /* you can ignore the code in here
    var tomato = findTomato(title, tomatoes);
    var classes = ["poster-width", "overlay"];
    var templateData = tomato ? prepareData(tomato, classes) : { query: title, classes: namespaceClasses(classes) };
    */
    eval(j.action); //evil eval!!
  });
});
```

UPDATED:

to avoid the `eval` define a json like:

```
json = [
{
  target: '.FFEC-Display',
  title: 'h3',
  actions: 
  [
    { action: 'find', target: '.movie-link' },
    'prepend'
  ]
}, 
{
  target: '.MovieItemsRotator .item',
  title: '.Title',
  actions: ['prepend']
}];
```

and the function:

```
$.each(json, function (index, j) {
  $(j.target).each(function (i, el) {
    var title = $(el).find(j.title).text().replace(blacklistRegexp, '').trim();
    /* you can ignore the code in here
    var tomato = findTomato(title, tomatoes);
    var classes = ["poster-width", "overlay"];
    var templateData = tomato ? prepareData(tomato, classes) : { query: title, classes: namespaceClasses(classes) };
    */
    var abomination = $(el);
    $.each(j.actions, function (k, action) {
      if (typeof action === "string") {
        //last action
        abomination[action](Handlebars.templates.ratings(templateData));
      } else if (action.target === undefined) {
        //action with no target, like siblings or something
        abomination = abomination[action.action]();
      } else {
        //action like find()
        abomination = abomination[action.action](action.target);
      }
    });
  });
});
```

Comment: Ooh fun. We might even be able to avoid the eval with an array of actions that looks something like `[{action: 'find', target: '.movie-link'}, 'prepend']`; add another loop where the `eval` was, call the first item in the actions array (call differently based on whether the `type` of the item is an `Object` or `String`) on `$(el)` and store the result, call the second item (if exists) on the stored value until the array is exhausted, and call the final result with the template's html. Would be sinfully complex and definitely wouldn't use the code, but it's definitely a fun solution

Comment: @CheapSteaks yes, you make a good point! and with the bracket notation of jquery ,i think it's possible to make the code out of eval. i will try to update the answer later.

Comment: I wrote a solution here, would love to compare with yours. Was practically giddy the entire time, lol https://gist.github.com/cheapsteak/5874339

Comment: @CheapSteaks i check your code, it's almost seems as mine, but you got a bit error with `abomination = abomination[action];` , seems it will lose bind of object after this. check this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/terryleonhart/mbhvu/1/).